# Macros dont working with POJOs (CLOSED)

Tags: json, macros, codenameone, pojo, mirah

i don't know what or if i'm doing it wrong, but the conversion from json to my POJOs just don't work. I'm with the dependencies updated. When i called the method "readJSONFromURL" my return always is the object with yours attributes with value NULL. All the libs are up to date.
 My Objects:

```
public class ListHall {

private List<Hall> Hall;

public void setHall(List<Hall> hall) {
    this.Hall = hall;
}

public List<Hall> getHall() {
    if (Hall == null) {
        this.Hall = new ArrayList<Hall>();
    }
    return Hall;
}
```

}

```
public class Hall {

private String id;
private String name;
private Integer count;

//getter and setters here
```

}

My DataMappers:

data_mapper ListHall:ListHallMapper
data_mapper Hall:HallMapper

My method conversor:

```
public ListHall mapHall() throws IOException {
    ListHallMapper returnListHallMapper = new ListHallMapper();
    HallMapper hallMapper = new HallMapper();
    DataMapper.createContext(Arrays.asList(returnListHallMapper,
            hallMapper),
            (DataMapper mapper) -> {
                mapper.setReadKeyConversions(Arrays.asList(DataMapper.CONVERSION_CAMEL_TO_SNAKE));
            });
    return returnListHallMapper.readJSONFromURL("http://192.168.0.16:7080/integration/hall", ListHall.class,"/ListHall");
}
```

My output JSON:

**{"ListHall":{"Hall":[{"id":"0","name":"Salão 1","count":"10"},{"id":"f6a495c1-be5e-4476-a362-5d42e572bfae","name":"Salão 3","count":"0"}]}}**

My result:
[image: NULL value]
My LIB:
[image: LIB]

What i'm doing it wrong?

Comment: What does the input json look like?

Comment: `{"ReturnList":[{"Hall":[{"id":"0","name":"Salão 1"}]}]}`

Comment: For now I'm converting the objects from the HashMap, but i want to simplify it with the macros

Comment: Notice the difference between "Returnlist" and "ReturnList".  Case matters.

Comment: The same result, in this case ...

Comment: Please update your question with these pertinent details.  Especially the json string and the Java code you are using to consume it.  The devil is in the details.

Comment: I just created a test project with *exactly* what you have, except I'm not getting the JSON from the network.  And it worked fine.
https://gist.github.com/shannah/289586ed115d52972a19929af758417a
Try my example and see if it works for you.  Then triple check the JSON that the server is returning.  (Check the network monitor in the simulator to see exactly what the server is returning to you).

Comment: I got the same result. You can release the source of this test project?

Comment: https://github.com/shannah/DataMapperTest

Comment: Thanks a lot. I dont quite understand, but after redo my Mapper this worked fine